# Using $_POST data to create a new html form value

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input, echo

I'm using `post` to send info to  my page. I'm using that to create a variable and pass that variable to a new `<input>`. However, when I submit the new form, the variable is blank.

The variable is created from post data:

```
$timenotstarted = $_POST["placeholder"];
```

Then inline in the html:

```
<form name="newform" method="post" action="insert.php">
<input type="text" name="timerset" value="<?php echo $timenotstarted; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><
</form>
```

When the new form is submitted, the variable whose `name="timerset"`, is blank.

When I echo `$timenotstarted` on the same page that this form is,

it will show its value. It just "goes away" when I try to use it in the new form.

Edit: Here's what's happeneing:
[image]

Not sure if this helps: http://forexguruguide.com/timer/insert.php

And here's the whole shabang:

```
<?php include 'connect.php';
$timenotstarted = $_GET["placeholder"];
$start = $_POST["start"];
$timerset = $_post["timerset"];
echo $timenotstarted . '<br />';
echo $start . '<br />';
echo $timerset . '<br />';
?>

<form name="timeform" method="get" action="insert.php">
<select name="placeholder">
  <option value="1">1 min</option>
  <option value="3">3 min</option>
  <option value="5">5 min</option>
  <option value="10">10 min</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Set timer">
</form>

<form name="startform" method="post" action="insert.php">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="start">
Timer set to: <input type="text" name="timerset" value="<?php print $timenotstarted?>">
<input type="Submit" value="Start Timer">
</form>

<?php

if ($start==1) {
  $target = time() + ($timerset * 60);
  mysql_query("UPDATE countdowntimer SET target='$target' WHERE id='0'");
  mysql_query("UPDATE countdowntimer SET timenotstarted='null' WHERE id='0'");
  echo 'Timer started' . '<br />';
  echo $target . '<br />';
  echo time(); }
else if (!empty($timenotstarted)) {
  $timenotstarted .= ":00";
  mysql_query("UPDATE countdowntimer SET timenotstarted='$timenotstarted'");
  echo 'Timer set to: ' . $timenotstarted; }
else {
  echo 'Set the timer then start the timer'; }
?>
```

Comment: so your first line of code is in `insert.php` ?

Comment: isn't the key 'placeholder' supposed to be 'timerset' ?

Comment: @jondavidjohn, Yes the first line is also in insert.php. To clarify, I'm posting to the same page.

Comment: Should be using `$_POST['timerset']` not `$_POST['placeholder']`, as @GWW said. Also, please use `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($timenotstarted); ?>` to avoid XSS attacks.

Comment: @Mark it's not to avoid anything. It's required by HTML standard. EVEN when nothing to protect from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's what FINALLY worked. I just rebuilt the second form...:

```
<form name="testyboy" method="post" action="insert.php">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="start">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php print $timenotstarted?>" name="testyboy">
<input type="submit" value="Start Timer">
</form>
```

It's identical. I have no idea what made it work....

Anyways thanks for everyone's efforts! Its much appreciated.

Comment: Only difference: on the `<input>` whose name is "testyboy", in the first version of the form, value came after name. Wonder if that was the problem...............

Answer (score 2):

shouldn't use POST for that. It's GET's job

```
<? if (!isset($_GET['placeholder'])): ?>
<form>
Enter placeholder:
<input type="text" name="placeholder" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<? else: ?>
<form name="newform" method="post" action="insert.php">
<input type="text" name="timerset" value="<?=htmlspecialchers($_GET["placeholder"])?>">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<? endif ?>
```

Comment: @col., so I submit the first form with method="get"?

Comment: @col., ok thanks! I'll give it a shot. If you have a sec: why?

Comment: @Andypandy if you feel reading docs, refer to rfc 2616. if you want to see with your eyes, try to push F5 on the second form or reach it using "back" button. You will get very annoying inquiry from the browser. If you have a sec too, I am curious, why such 2-step form?

Comment: @col., that isn't working for me... same issue as was having with post. I'm going to try and take a screenshot to illustrate... Thanks for your help I really appreciate it! I'm sure this will be a learning experience. The 2 step form is to start a timer... the first form sets the timer to a certain time, then the second form starts the timer using the information passed when setting it.

Comment: @Andy I can't get it at all. A timer? how's that? It seems it's your timer not working (and it shouldn't), not this primitive form that works always. How do you use entered value? in javascript? Why second form? Why not to start timer right after user press a button in the first form?

Comment: @col., i've posted a pic. Yeah its screwy haha, but I have no idea what I'm doing. Users won't be starting the timer, just a moderator type person.

Comment: @col. and also, i have to set it 2 different values, 1 min, 3 min, 5 min, and 10 min

Comment: @Andy why not to make it just 1 form?

Comment: @col., I want to be able to set the timer (so as to build suspense for those seeing it), and then start it when I everyone is ready. Its going to be a countdown timer for someone to do something.... So, i want to set it to an amount and have that in my mysql table, and then when I click start timer it makes that value null and sets a time into "target" that is 1 or 3 or 5 or 10 minutes away

Comment: @Andy why cannot you make a form that contain both select box with time interval and "start timer" submit? It seems you're trying to complicate your task unnecessary

Comment: @col. I'm not sure how I'd do that. Its really 2 things going on. My mysql table has 1 record. It has 3 columns (id=0, timernotset=[kind of a placeholder where i can put a value that will let everyone know how long the timer will count down from. this value is not always the same], and target[this is timestamp made by entering php `time() + ($timerset * 60)` into it. The same function that enters that into the table, also sets timernotset to "null")..

Comment: @col  The first thing going on sets the "timernotset" colum to a value.The second thing that goes on is a "start" button for the timer, which uses the "timernotset" value

Comment: @col dude i really appreciate your help! I just can't figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you're doing wrong from your post, but here's the basics on how to do it right:

#### page1.php

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

#### page2.php

```
<form>
<input name="foo2" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['foo']); ?>"/>
</form>
```

Comment: no that didn't work either. What I'm doing is posting something to a page with a form on it. I'm using php to populate an input value (just like you did) however when I submit the next form, it doesn't submit any value. In fact, I've set it as `<input type="text">` and it even populates the text box with the value, but when I submit the form, it doesn't submit the value... it doesn't submit any value.

Comment: try on page2.php, a single line: `<?php print_r($_POST);` and run it. If $_POST is empty, try `$_HTTP_POST_VARS` instead. You may be using an old PHP.